# Symfony2 - send javascript to the bottom of page from child view

Tags: symfony, twig

7.6 i want to load a javascript file included from my child view after the javsscripts loaded from base.html.twig

for example, here is my base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Benerite | {% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>

        {% stylesheets
            'assets/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.min.css'
            'assets/gentelella-master/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            filter='cssrewrite' output='css/compiled/app.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body class="nav-md">
        <div class="container body">

            <div class="main_container">
                {{ include('::_navigation.html.twig') }}
                {{ include('::_topnav.html.twig') }}

                <!-- page content -->
                <div class="right_col" role="main">{% block body %}{% endblock %}</div>
                <!-- /page content -->

                <!-- footer content -->
                <footer>
                    <div class="">
                        <p class="pull-right">
                            <span class="lead"> <i class="fa fa-database"></i> Benerite</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </footer>
                <!-- /footer content -->                
            </div>                
        </div>

        <div id="custom_notifications" class="custom-notifications dsp_none">
            <ul class="list-unstyled notifications clearfix" data-tabbed_notifications="notif-group"></ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id="notif-group" class="tabbed_notifications"></div>
        </div>

        {% javascripts
            'assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
            'assets/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js'
            output='js/compiled/main.js'
        %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my child form in which i have included a js file at the end

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h1>Privilege edit</h1>

    {{ form(edit_form) }}

        <ul class="record_actions">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('privilege') }}">
            Back to the list
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
</ul>
<script src="{{my_custom_js file}}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

When I load the page, I want the js file render after the js file included from the base.html.twig

Is there any solution for my issue?? please help me

Answer (score 0):

In base template you have two blocks,  base and javascripts.
Create one more, somthing like that `childs_javascripts` after `javascripts` block.
And in childe template just use `childs_javascripts` like you use block `body`

```
{% block childs_javascripts %}
<script src="{{my_custom_js file}}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the block and call parent block with `parent()` twig function.

base.html.twig

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets ... %}...{% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts ... %}...{% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

page.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    inner content
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets additional styles %}...{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts additional scripts %}...{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```